# rosbridge install problem

Tags: ros-melodic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have : Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS / ROS melodic (all updated to latest)

When I try to install ros bridge suite with command:

sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-rosbridge-server

i get this errors:

```
Err:1 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-rosbridge-library amd64 0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.025706
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:2 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-rosapi amd64 0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.030429
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-rosauth amd64 0.1.7-2bionic.20190320.155717
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs amd64 0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.025715
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ros-melodic-rosbridge-server amd64 0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.030720
  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosbridge-library/ros-melodic-rosbridge-library_0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.025706_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosapi/ros-melodic-rosapi_0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.030429_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosauth/ros-melodic-rosauth_0.1.7-2bionic.20190320.155717_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs/ros-melodic-rosbridge-msgs_0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.025715_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosbridge-server/ros-melodic-rosbridge-server_0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.030720_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I think that this is since version 0.11.2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329330/rosbridge-install-problem/) by [jernejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/44300/jernejp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-28**:
This reads like #q325039.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
E: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosbridge-library/ros-melodic-rosbridge-library_0.11.1-1bionic.20190508.025706_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.233.100 80]
```

On [packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosbridge-library](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/pool/main/r/ros-melodic-rosbridge-library), I do find some `.deb` files but with timestam in 20190601 or newer. By updating your apt list by `apt-get update` then re-try `apt-get install`, `apt-get` should point to the right URL.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jernejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/44300/jernejp/) on 2019-07-26**:
alredy did that but with no help becouse of :
https://discourse.ros.org/t/new-gpg-keys-deployed-for-packages-ros-org/9454

when i updated keys works OK